# Jquery select the element h3

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I select  element in this HTML using jquery selectors.

```
<div class = 'divOne">
</div>
<div class = 'divTwo">
  <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: `'divOne"` ???? ok where are you stuck ??

Comment: Here you go: `$('h3')`

Comment: This is really jQuery 101 - the kind of thing you should be capable of researching yourself. http://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.divOne').siblings('.divTwo').children('h3')
```

Comment: This is what i needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to select the `h3` element.

But you have to fix your `HTML` first. While, when writing `HTML5`, in general it's possible to use single-quotes. **But**, you have to use them at the **start** and the **end** of the value like this: `<div class='divOne' />` or `<div class="divOne" />`

```js
$('.divTwo > h3').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divOne">
</div>
<div class="divTwo">
  <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".divOne")` to perform jquery functions on first div
`$(".divTwo")` to perform jquery functions on second div
`$("h3")` to perform jquery functions on header element

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery selector and select `h3` with `$('h3')`. But maybe you have more than one `h3`-tags in your code. 
In that case you could give the `h3` a class and select the class with the selector.

Example:

```
<div class = "divOne">
</div>
<div class = "divTwo">
  <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
```

In this case use: `$('h3');`

**OR**

```
<div class = "divOne">
</div>
<div class = "divTwo">
  <h3 class="myClass">Title</h3>
</div>
```

And in this case you use `$('.myClass');`

**-----------**

In the above I explained how you could select an h3-tag, but it does work with all elements ofcourse ;)

I also noticed that you use single quotes and double quotes in your HTML (`'divOne"`)

Do not use both for a single attribute. Just `"divOne"` or `'divOne'`.